# Free jqGrid Menu Context - Menu off set

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Whenever the menu is on the very right side or the very low level of the screen, it is being cut and masked instead of shifting left (or up) dynamically.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="contextMenu" id="runContextMenu" style="display:none">
```

My Javascript code is:

```
$("tr.jqgrow",'#'+gridName).contextMenu('runContextMenu', {
    bindings: {
    },
    onContextMenu: function (event, menu) {
    } });
```

Comment: Same symptom can be seen here: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithContextmenu2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version exactly of `contextMenu` you use? Which version of jQuery UI you use? Which version of free jqGrid you use?

The problem, which you describes seems to be pure problem of `contextMenu`. There are different version `contextMenu` plugin. For example one can use `jquery.contextmenu-ui.js` from `plugins` folder. It contains [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/plugins/jquery.contextmenu-ui.js#L208-L216), which fix the vertical position of the the menu. Moreover, I'd recommend you to use `$('#'+gridName).contextMenu` instead of `$("tr.jqgrow",'#'+gridName).contextMenu`. It makes only one binding to the grid instead of binding to every rows of the grid and remake the binding in `loadComplete` after every paging, sorting or filtering. The `event` parameter of  `onContextMenu` contains full information about the clicked row. You can use

```
var rowid = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
```

to get the `rowid`. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/plugins/jquery.createcontexmenufromnavigatorbuttons.js#L52).

You can use alternative another `contextMenu` plugin, like https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/ for example.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, yes, I'm using the one inside the plugin directory. I eventually had to change it. I'll use your tip for binding the grid instead each row.